# Razor Pages link is mis-rendering based on the current page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a Razor Pages app with the following markup in my **_Layout.cshtml** file.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Reports
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="Reports" asp-page="/Invoice/Index">Invoices</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="Reports" asp-page="/ProfitabilityByCustomer/Index">Profitability by Customer</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="Reports" asp-page="/ProfitabilityByLocation/Index">Profitability by Location</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="Reports" asp-page="/CostAudit/Index">Cost Audit</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="Reports" asp-page="/ChangeLogs/Index">Change Logs</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Notice the last link (to **/ChangeLogs/Index**). This page has a page route (`@page "{id?}"`).

When I manually navigate to **/Reports/ChangeLogs/61**, the markup above renders as:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Reports
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Reports/Invoice">Invoices</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Reports/ProfitabilityByCustomer">Profitability by Customer</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Reports/ProfitabilityByLocation">Profitability by Location</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Reports/CostAudit">Cost Audit</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Reports/ChangeLogs/61">Change Logs</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Somehow, the fact that the current page is **/Reports/ChangeLogs/61**, is causing the link in the menu to render with this route value!

I can't explain this. And I need to stop it from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes will inherit values from the current page if they have not been specified.
So specify a blank value;

```cs
<a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="Reports" asp-page="/ChangeLogs/Index" asp-route-id="">Change Logs</a>
```

Comment: Yes, that fixes it. But I'm still not sure why it was inheriting them. I see no good reason for that.